# Variables in SSH command within script

Tags: linux, ssh

I wanna know if it is possible to use variables in an SSH command within a /bin/bash (bash?) script.

Example

```
ssh $user@$ip
```

Does this work if I set the variables to the proper values? Any help would be appreciated, even if it is a totally different and more efficient way of doing this.

Comment: What happened when you tried it?

Comment: Explain what happened when you tried this, which wasn't what you expected to happen.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's fine, but I would use

```
ssh ${user}@${ip}
```

because the variables aren't isolated by whitespace, and you want to be clear to future readers that `@` is not a special modifier on the variable name.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it is perfectly possible. Bash first substitutes the user and ip variables for the values you give in your script. After that, bash invokes ssh.